# In multiple Name Nodes configuration if one Name Node Fails?

Tags: hadoop-yarn

What Resource Manager does if the job request is associated with the failed Name Node namespace. Say for example ..../finance is the namespace associated with namespace.

Which Name Name will serve this information to Resource manager as Name Node are Isolated?

Thanks in advance.
Suman Kumar

Answer (score 0):

The HDFS HA will handle the scenario as there will be standby Name Node for every Active Name Node.

Please correct if my understanding is wrong.